# bootable live usb doesn't boot, KNOPPIX

Tags: linux, debian, usb-drive, disk-image

I have been trying to make a bootable live USB of KNOPPIX. I downloaded the .iso image, checked the sha1sum with the one that was given and it was all correct. Then tried both the options, using cp as well as dd so that bootable image iso would boot. While it mounts and shows me the contents, it doesn't boot.

I used the command shared therein [preparing a usb drive to be bootable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233485/preparing-a-usb-drive-to-be-bootable/233520#233520)

But it didn't/doesn't work. I also asked at superuser just to see if there might be a UEFI thing but turns out I am not running UEFI

https://superuser.com/questions/981443/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-the-system-you-are-on-is-bios-or-uefi/981451#981451

which in turn got me here [How to know if I'm booting using UEFI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148356/how-to-know-if-im-booting-using-uefi)

and this is what efibootmgr had to say about that:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr
[sudo] password for shirish: 
efibootmgr: EFI variables are not supported on this system.
```

This simply means I am running legacy BIOS.

Now as far 'burning' the live USB I used the method outlined by @teppic in the Q&A shared above

```
dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=2048
```

I didn't use a partition and kept the block-size as was shared by him. Is there some more correct way to know if it's done or something else that I could have done so that it boots.

Also, before I forget, UEFI/Legacy BIOS is configured to boot when it detects a bootable live USB. I booted a nice live image I have and it booted into that.